# To rewrite the sentence using "It seems ..."

Tags: sentence-structure

If you rewrite the following sentence A "It seems ..." to a sentence whose subject is "Nature", which is grammatically correct among B to D?

> A. It seems that nature cannot be controlled.
>
> B. Nature does not seem to be able to be controlled.
>
> C. Nature seems not be able to be controlled.
>
> D. Nature cannot seem to be controlled.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please add your own takes on this question.

Answer (score -1):

You have to note that "nature" is already the subject in the fragment:

> nature cannot be controlled.

If you want to start the sentence with nature, then you can write:

> Nature is presumably uncontrollable.

or:

> Nature cannot be controlled, as it seems.